How to subscribe to the Workbook.SheetActivate event?
I want to subscribe to the Workbook.SheetActivate event of my excel Application which I use as a dynamic object so that I am not dependent on the specific version.
Instantiation and EventHandler:
public static dynamic NewInstance()
{
    Type excelType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application");
    return Activator.CreateInstance(excelType);
}

private static void Excel_SheetActivate(dynamic Sh)
{
    Sh.Protect("test");
}

If I now run the whole thing in a console application (.Net 5), this works without any problems:
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    dynamic excel = NewInstance();
    excel.SheetActivate += new Action<object>((obj) => Excel_SheetActivate(obj));
}

But in a Winforms application (.Net 4.6.1) this does not work:
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    dynamic excel = NewInstance();
    excel.SheetActivate += new Action<object>((obj) => Excel_SheetActivate(obj));
}

Here I get the following error:Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'The System.Action<object> type cannot be implicitly converted to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.AppEvents_SheetActivateEventHandler'.
The types of the dynamic object also differ.
Console:  dynamic {System.__ComObject}
Winforms: dynamic {Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass}

So how can I also subscribe to the event in the Winform application?

Have you tried creating a Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.AppEvents_SheetActivateEventHandler instead of an Action<object>?  There are lots of differences between .NET Core and .NET Framework, and having to be more explicit in the older framework is not surprising.

@DavidBrowne-Microsoft This is only possible if I reference the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll, right? I am looking for a dynamic / independent solution.

Why not use .NET Core for your WinForms app?

Like a Class Library?

Clearly you have not actually removed the dependency on the Excel type library.  Remove it from the project to get ahead.  Workaround is here.

@HansPassant I created a new project especially for testing, so the Excel dependency is definitely not there. When I use the workaround I get the following error at Delegate.CreateDelegate: Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type. I think I will use David's solution and use the .dll. But it would be nice to know why this doesn't work in .Net Framework.

Fixed the error by making Excel_SheetActivate non static. It now works perfectly. @HansPassant You can post this as an answer if you like.

"Like a Class Library?" No.  Write your WinForms application using .NET 8, instead of .NET Framework.  You can build it as a self-contained .EXE for Windows so it doesn't require any .NET install or have any external dependencies. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/
